# Do I need to use Express or other library to make a server that only return JSONs using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, react-native

I'm testing node js and so much questions are coming to my head. I want to make a server to a mobile app that just response data I need from a database. That is not so complicated but all people I see use Express with node but when I take a look to Express seems that is like it only give you help if your target is a web app (probably I'm wrong). I've reached get a data from my mongodb database calling my node server but all in node js raw code. I want to know if exists other library for API REST use that could help in a mobile develop or in fact, if I will have to still working in raw node (that is not a really problem). I'm new in node so probably I'm leaving some concepts. To make this the app I'm using React-Native. It could be important to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express is a framework that will simplify development **alot**. You are not forced to use it, just keep in mind that without it, you will have no router, no middlewares, and no anything coming with Express.

You can, but it will be harder if your app becomes big.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use express to do the same. Or you an use any other framework like sails,koa. But most of the frameworks are based on express and from my experience express is the best to do this. I have been running express with similar purpose for the past 3 years.

Express provides basic features like routing, creating server, error handling.You can plug whatever libraries to express to do better.